# Why does my label disappear on button click?

Tags: qt, label

I am brand new to Qt development and am trying to make a simple "Hello, World" with a toggle-button. I have something like this:

[image]

with the corresponding code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked) {
        ui->label->setText("Hello, World!");
    } else {
        ui->label->setText("");
    }
}
```

My goal is to change the label's text either from blank to "Hello, World!" or vice versa on a button click.

Currently the label only stays blank. Earlier the default text was "TextLabel", and on a button-click, it would change from "TextLabel" to blank, which is almost correct.

I've tried different options like `on_pushButton_clicked`, but to no avail.

I know the solution is a simple one -- can anyone point me in a good direction?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text().isEmpty() ? "Hello, World!" : "");
}
```

Comment: 1. Checked becomes unused.
2. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure this method gets called? add a breakpoint or use a qDebug to verify.

Comment: @erip Then use the [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal, that way you wont have an unused `checked` variable. Also the `toggled` signal is for checkable buttons. You cannot toggle an uncheckable button. Have you set your button to be checkable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your callback method as below :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT         
    bool checked;
    QPushButton *my_button;
    private slots:
      void handleButton();     
};
```

Then in your `Constructor` you need to connect `Signal and Slot` as below :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
   checked = 0;
   connect(my_button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (on_pushButton_toggled()));
}
```

Your call back method will be like this. You can toggle your flag in this method as every time you click this `SLOT` will be called.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_toggled()
{
    checked = ~checked;
    if(checked) {
      ui->label->setText("Hello, World!");
    } else {
       ui->label->setText("");
    }
}
```

I hope this will work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

`QPushButton` is not checkable by default; you need to call `QAbstractButton::setCheckable(true);` before you can really use the `QAbstractButton::toggled` signal in any meaningful way. What happens in your code is that your slot is being called with the value `false` passed every single time because the button simply isn't checkable.